# React.forwardRef complaining TypeError: Component is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Errors or warning in my pages are handled by ValidationState, a component that takes **validationResult**s and checks if a specific field **msgKey** has a message to display.

This component has to receive a **ref** that will enable me to scroll towards it if it contains a message. Passing the ref, I received an error saying that [I must use forwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html), but I can't get it to work as it says: TypeError: Component is not a function

*ValidationState.js*

```
import {validation} from "./validationResult";
import {Box} from "@mui/material";

const sxDef= {
    error: {
        color: '#ca0000',
        width: '100%',
        backgroundColor: '#ca000014',
        padding: '4px',
        borderBottom: '1px dotted'
    },
    warn: {
        color: '#d59f00'
    },
    info: {
        color: '#333333'
    },
}

const ValidationState = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    const {validationResult, msgKey, sx} = props

    console.log( 'executing ValidationState' )

    const state = validationResult.getState(msgKey)
    if(!state)
        return <div></div>

    const severityClass = state.level === validation.ERROR ? sxDef.error : state.level == validation.WARNING ? sxDef.warn : sxDef.info
    return (
        <Box sx={[sx, severityClass]} ref={ref}>
            {state.message}
        </Box>
    )

})

export default ValidationState
```

I wanted to enable scrolling to the last error message by passing it a ref created by the parent component

*IssueFieldsForm.js*

```
export default function IssueFieldsForm(props) {
    const [scrollTopRef, setScrollTop] = useScrollIntoView()
///...
return (
           <Grid item>
                <ValidationState validationResult={validationState} msgKey='edit.errors.entityNotSelected'
                                 sx={sx.validationMessage} ref={scrollTopRef}/>
                <MapSearch
                    onEntitySelected={onMarkerSelected}
                    onMarkersChanged={onMarkersChanged}
                    onMarkerSelected={onMarkerSelected}
                    onIssueDataChanged={onIssueDataChanged}
                    selected={issue.entity}
                    bounds={issue.maps}
                    markers={markers}
                />
            </Grid> 
  )
}
```

Where the hook looks like this:

*hooks.js*

```
export function useScrollIntoView() {
    const htmlElRef = useRef(null)
    const scrollIntoView = () => {
        if( !htmlElRef.current )
            return

        htmlElRef.current.scrollIntoView()
    }

    return [htmlElRef, scrollIntoView]
}
```

Comment: The error message I get when I pass ref directly is : next-dev.js?3515:32 Warning: ValidationState: `ref` is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in `undefined` being returned

Comment: What is supposed to do this line `htmlElRef.current.scrollIntoView()` in your hook?

Comment: It scrolls to the last ValidationState item which didn't return null (or nothing). This part works, it's the ref part that is broken

Comment: Ok, could you add your Box component code ?